# Visual Studio C# Redirect to a game over screen

Tags: c#, console

i am a beginner in C# and i have to hand in an assignment soon and i need help with one thing. also i am using Console Application

In the game you have to go through different rooms and kill "zombies" so far it will go to unlimited rooms but i want it to stop once the user has done the 25th room, i have written code that should work but i don't know why it is not working. here is the code i used

any help appreciated.

```
{
            if (room1 >25)
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You made it passed all 25 Rooms. You Defeated all the mobs");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to Quit...");
        }
```

Comment: try something your self and if you get any errors, then use this site.

Comment: @Alex Craig please read how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Ok. here it is smaller http://pastebin.com/XH5p63ta

Comment: @AlexCraig I know how you can accomplish this, you can accomplish this task by doing some coding on your own as well as showing us what you have done on  your own.. also read the link under `Ask Question` on how to `Ask a Question` this is not a code provider service site so please edit this question to provide exactly what was mentioned in the previous comments

Comment: Ok, Then, is this better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need curly braces after your if statement, like so.

```
if (room1 >25)
{
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You made it passed all 25 Rooms. You Defeated all the mobs");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to Quit...");
}
```

Without them what you're saying is

```
if room1>25, then write "".
Regardless of room number, do everything else.
```

That's because in C#, you CAN have an if statement without curly braces, but in that case it MUST be only one line long. So your code above is actually equivalent to this:

```
if (room1 >25)
{
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You made it passed all 25 Rooms. You Defeated all the mobs");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to Quit...");
```

Comment: i have tried that but it is still not working, when you enter the first room it says Congratulations you have won.